# jenkins git how to reset submodules between builds

Tags: git, jenkins

It appears with jenkins and the git plugin, that any local modifications (to the "root" repository) are reverted after each checkout, prior to each build (console output shows this):

> git checkout -f efdf34a30d977606ba63ccc19927b1090b5e4994

however, if has git submodules, it only runs

> git submodule update --init

which doesn't actually revert any local modifications from previous runs.  Which is somewhat inconsistent.  Is there is a work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appears that an "additional behaviors" "clean after checkout" option (if added) adds a

> git submodule foreach --recursive git reset --hard # timeout=10
>
> git submodule foreach --recursive git clean -fdx # timeout=10

which accomplishes the desired goal.